Clarification on the proof that an $a\times b$ rectangle can be covered by 1 × n rectangles iff n|a or n|b
I came across this problem in Arthur Engel book and I don't understand at all the solution given there for the case when we assume we can cover the rectangle by $1\times n$ tiles. The solution provided is the following.
Let $a = nq+r$, the expresion obtained when dividing $a$ by $n$ with residue $r$. Color the board as indicated in .
There
are bq + b squares of each of the colors 1, 2, . . . , r, and there are bq squares of
each of the colors 1, . . . , n. The h horizontal 1 × n tiles of a covering each cover
one square of each color. Each vertical 1 × n tile covers n squares of the same color.
After the h horizontal tiles are placed, there will remain (bq + b − h) squares of
each of the colors 1, . . . , r and bq − h of each of the colors r + 1, . . . , n. Thus
n|bq + b − h and n|bq − h. But if n divides two numbers, it also divides their
difference: (bq + b − h) − (bq − h) = b.
The way the board is colored is not explicitely stated and the coloration referenced is not clear because it only colors each coulumn horizontally from $1$ to $n$ and it repeats this coloration after $n$. But I don't understand why this coloration is taken and the first claims it makes around it, like why there are $b+bq$ squares of the first $r$ squares and why are there $bq$ of the colors from $1$ to $n$. Any clarification would be greatelly appreciated.

Sorry, I just added it

What is $q$? I doubt Engel use it without defining it...

q is just the quotient of n when you divide a by n

That information, H4, and any other important information that you have left out, should be edited into your question, not buried in the comments. (For instance, the title of the Arthur Engel book – he may have written more than one!)

I believe there may be slight typos in the book. I'm not totally sure, but I'm guessing they were using the following definitions/string of logic:

Let $a = qn + r$ by the division/remainder theorem, so $0 \le r < n$, (assume $n$ doesn't divide $a$, or else we are done)
so in the picture, $q = 2$ and $r = 2$. $q$ accounts for the fact that (for example looking at the figure) the colors 2 and 3 have $q$ columns, and $r$ accounts for the fact that the colors 0 and $1 = r-1$ have $q + 1$ columns. As such, there will be $b(q+1)$ squares of the colors $0$ to $1 = r- 1$, and $bq$ squares of the colors $r$ to $n - 1$. If we instead label the colors starting at 1 instead of zero, this is the same as saying that the colors $1$ to $r$ appears $bq + b$ times, and the colors $r+1$ to $n$ appear $bq$ times,
the motivation for doing this coloring scheme is that each horizontal tile will cover exactly one of each colors, and each vertical tile will cover all the same color, which makes accounting for the colors easy,
after placing $h$ horizontal tiles, each color will lose $h$ tiles, so we are left with $bq + b - h$ tiles for the colors $1$ to $r$ and $bq - h$ tiles for the colors $r+1$ to $n$. Then, each of the vertical tiles will only be able to remove $n$ from either of these numbers since vertical tiles only cover one color at a time,
so $n$ divides $bq +b - h$ and $bq - h$, so it must divide $b$.

So we have found that $n$ divides either $a$ or $b$, as desired. Let me know if that makes more sense!

Thank you so much it did help a lot
